# Integration of D365 with RabbitMQ using C# to Read and Write data in Queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, rabbitmq-exchange

I want to integrate RabbitMQ with D365 CRM to write/read data from/to Queue from D365
Is there any plugin or alternate to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using RabbitMQ as a message broker in Dynamics CRM data interfaces

https://github.com/lucasalexander/Crm-Sample-Code#crmmessagequeuing